# Why are all my packages refusing to install?

Tags: apt, package-management

I'm running on 16.04 and I'm trying to install various packages for development, namely `libglib2.0-dev` for a project I'm working on.  But this isn't the only package that has done this lately.  Getting MySQL installed this week was a pain.  I keep getting the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libglib2.0-dev : Depends: libglib2.0-0 (= 2.48.0-1ubuntu4) but 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 is to be installed
                  Depends: libglib2.0-bin (= 2.48.0-1ubuntu4)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is virtually the exact same thing that was happening with my MySQL installation.  I've searched around and found some recommendations to use `aptitude install` and `apt-get install -f` but none of these have worked.  I've also done the due dilligence of `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` as well as checking **Main Server** in Download From in Software & Updates.  I tried sticking it in a bag of granola for a week, but it didn't seem to do anything.

Any idea what's going on?  I see a few of these threads around with no real solutions.

As per suggestion, the output is of apt-cache policy alibglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin is:

```
libglib2.0-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.48.0-1ubuntu4
  Version table:
     2.48.0-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libglib2.0-0:
  Installed: 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1
  Candidate: 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.48.0-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libglib2.0-bin:
  Installed: 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1
  Candidate: 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 2.48.1-1~ubuntu16.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.48.0-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy libglib2.0-dev libglib2.0-0 libglib2.0-bin` ?

Comment: I have done so.  Does this data have some implication about the state of my packages?

Comment: Does simply running `sudo apt-get clean` followed by retrying your original installation command solve it? You have had a PPA or something that provided newer versions of some libraries which got cached on your disk and are incompatible with the version you need.

Comment: Neither clean nor autoclean solve the problem.  The MySQL installation I'm talking about was a 5.6 installation, which required me to use the old packages from Wily.  This is probably why I have some bad cached packages, but I would have thought that they would remove themselves with clean and/or autoclean.

Comment: You need to open Software & Updates > Updates tab & enable the 1st. two, -security &  -updates. Then update your sources & proceed. (- for reference see - http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial-updates/libglib2.0-dev , it's a xenial-update package

Comment: This worked, please post as an answer so I can accept.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Unmet dependencies remain in your sources.list..u need to refresh in order to install further packages so here you go :

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then, type in

```
sudo software-properties-gtk
```

[image]
This will open software-properties-gtk and a newsources.list will be created automatically.

Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.

Tick all the boxes then click on Revert then click close.

Need to restore default repositories

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

(it is good practice to backup this file before installing to recover if such things happen)